# Hibernate says Column 'idRol' cannot be null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, null, primary-key

I'm trying to save an usuariRol that have a reference to usuari and a reference to rol. 
I check that the Usuari object and Rol object has their ids but hibernate is telling me that idRol cannot be null.

Is there a problem with the mapping?

**Table t_usuariRol**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_usuariRol"
        , uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"idUsuari", "idRol"}))

public class UsuariRol implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idUsuari")
private Usuari usuari;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idRol")
private Rol rol;
```

**Table a_rol**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_rol")
public class Rol implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1979744578967968079L;

static final String PREFIX = "pia.entity.Rol.";
public static final String findAll = PREFIX + "findAll";
public static final String findById = PREFIX + "findById";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(length = 45)
private String nom;
```

**UsuariBean.saveUsuariRol**

```
public void saveUsuariRol(){
 UsuariRol urol;
 Usuari usuari = usuariMgr.findById(1);
 Rol rol = rolMgr.findById(2);  //rol is not null has id and nom
 urol = new UsuariRol(usuari, rol);
 try {
     usuariRolMgr.save(urol);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("error usuarirol with id");
 }
```

}

**Error**

```
Hibernate: 
/* insert UsuariRol / 
insert 
 into
 t_usuariRol
 (idRol, idUsuari, version) 
 values
 (?, ?, ?)
10:25:39,184 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-52) SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
10:25:39,186 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-52) Column 'idRol' cannot be null
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'idRol' cannot be null
```

**RolManager**

```
@Stateless
public class RolManager {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbPU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Rol findById(int id) {
        return this.em.find(Rol.class, id);
    }

    public List<Rol> all() {
        return this.em.createNamedQuery(Rol.findAll, Rol.class).
                getResultList();
    }

    public Rol save(Rol rol) {
        if (rol.getId() == null) {
            this.em.persist(rol);
            return rol;
        } else {
            return this.em.merge(rol);
        }
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        try {
            Rol reference = this.em.getReference(Rol.class, id);
            this.em.remove(reference);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            //we want to remove it
            logger.error("Entity not found exeption: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `rolMgr.findById(2);` returning you this object? Is it returned via hibernate DAO or some other class variable?

Comment: I added the class RolManager where you can see what you asked. The method save is similar in UsuariRolManager. Every method from manager obtain em injected.

Comment: Could it be that the entity does not have object Rol detached from entityManager?. I am only open and close entityManager in findById and save methods.

Comment: This generally occurs when the dependent objects aren't saved. That's why it's advised to save them before saving parent entity. In your case, this error should occur when `rol` is not there in DB.

Comment: In your `UsuariRol` class, if you add cascade parameter like `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on `private Rol rol;` field, then does it solve your issue?

Comment: @RamanSahasi with the change you proposed it allows to save the object but it creates a new rol with same nom and a new id

Comment: then the problem is that hibernate can't track previous object. You need to use the same session to fetch previous object and with the same session without closing, you need to save this object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136752/discussion-between-joe-and-raman-sahasi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I can infer is that hibernate's session can't track your child object. Entities loaded from one session and saved in another can cause problems.

So in order to fix this issue.

1. Start a session and transaction
2. Fetch the child object
3. Save parent object
4. Then commit

Use the same session for all the above process.

Comment: It's a solution that works fine but I'll keep looking for the optimal one